# How to access my ftp sever over the internet?

Tags: firewall, ftp, azure, windows-server-2016

I have Windows Server 2016 running on an Azure VM, and I'm trying to get ftp running on it.
FTP role is installed, ports 21 and 20 are opened in the firewall and in Azure portal.
And still port 20 doesn't seem to be open, since the port scanner times out. My Firewall log doesn't show the attempt, sp I guess it's blocked in AZure somewhere, but my port 20 is definitely opened (inbound. Do I have to do anything outbound?).
I also opened ports 7000-7014 in Azure (Windows Firewall has a predefined FTS passive data rule with 1024-65535, so I didn't add anything here), and put those in the "FTP Firewall support" item of the IIS and put in the external IP of my VM.

When going ftp://localhost from within my VM, I login with the user I authorized in the IIS, and it works how it should.
When accessing it over dns name over the internet, I tried to login with my credentials, and I get a timeout. i tried username, \username, myPC\username, |username, and they all do the same. THe connection does work over the internet via cli with ftp myDNSname -> |username -> password.

Edit: I did search the internet, and then stackexchange, but didn't find anything that might explain what's going wrong here. So I turned to you, hoping you would help me.

**Edit**: Pictures to show the current state.

Another edit: Log from FileZilla:
PWD
257 "/" is current directory.
TYPE I
200 Type set to I.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (13,95,157,108,225,30).
LIST
Die Datenverbindung konnte nicht hergestellt werden: ENETUNREACH - Netzwerk nicht erreichbar // It says network unreachable
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
// After this comes a timeout

[image: Azure inbound rules]

[image: Firewall inbound rules]

[image: FTP site bindings]

Comment: Please explain your downvote, so I can improve my post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the windows firewall seems to allow all traffic that’s required, we also need to enable stateful FTP filtering on the firewall:

```
netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFtp enable
```

Then restart the FTP windows service and we should be up and running:

```
net stop ftpsvc
net start ftpsvc
```

[image]

Comment: It works in firefox now :D Unfortunately, FileZilla still doesn't work, sending the same log as before. Any Idea how Firefox work but FileZilla doesn't?

Comment: Update: It works in Explorer too now, problem solved :D Imaginary bonus points if you can tell me how to get FileZilla running, so I can learn for the next time :)

Comment: @MarlonRegenhardt, "network unreachable" here a good article about the issue, please refer to the link:https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/10443

Answer (score 0):

You have to forward ports 20-21 on your router to point to the server. Then you will be able to access the FTP over the internet via IP or domain name.

UPDATE:
Seems to be working...
[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYvVK.png)

Comment: I did that, as stated in my post. Also my router in this case it's the Microsoft azure portal. I'm not home right now, but when I get home I can make some screenshots.

Comment: oh ok, i read wrong. i would check IIS's FTP site bindings. make sure they arent set to bind to the internal IP. it should be bound to `*` for "any"

Comment: I have several bindings set up, for *, local PC name, external DNS name. From within the VM, all of these work.

Comment: can you post a picture?

Comment: Added some pictures. Tell me if you need anything more, not sure I got everything connected to this.

Comment: i updated my answer and showed that it is in fact working. How exactly are you even trying to access the FTP site?

Comment: oh ok, i just saw your updated question. so CLI works but the web browser method doesnt. Do you need to use the web browser? what if you use filezilla?

Comment: I tried FileZilla, unfortunately it doesn't work either. I added the part of filezillas log to my post. I checked the servers firewalls log, it doesn't show anything blocked.